# BasicForm.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')in react while using useReducer,please help to solve this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, trim, use-reducer

I a'm getting error

```
BasicForm.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')
    at BasicForm.js:7:1
```

My Code

//---my use-input-hook---------

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
const intialInputState=()=>{
  return{
    value:"",
    isTouched:false,
  }
}

const inputStateReducer=(state,action)=>{
  if(action.type==='INPUT'){
    return{value:action.value,isTouched:state.isTouched}
  }
  if(action.type==='BLUR'){
    return{isTouched:true,value:state.value}
  }
  if(action.type==='RESET'){
    return{value:'',isTouched:false}
  }
  return inputStateReducer;
}

const UseInput = (validateValue) => {
  const[inputState,dispatch] =useReducer(inputStateReducer,intialInputState);
  const valueIsValid = validateValue(inputState.value);
  const hasError = !valueIsValid && inputState.isTouched;
  
  const valueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    dispatch({type:"INPUT",value:event.target.value})
    //setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
  };
  const inputBlurHandler = (event) => {
    dispatch({type:"BLUR"})
  };
  const reset = () => {
    dispatch({type:"RESET"})
  };
  
  return {
    value: inputState.value,
    isValid:valueIsValid,
    hasError,
    valueChangeHandler,
    inputBlurHandler,
    reset,
  };
};
export default UseInput;
```

here is my basic input form

//---Basic Input form------------

```
import UseInput from "../hooks/use-input";
//creating this function outside the component so it will not create always whenever the component is recreated
const isEmail = (value) => value.includes("@");
const BasicForm = (props) => {
  //----Using Input Hook for First-Name
  const {
    value: enteredFirstName,
    isValid: firstNameIsValid,
    hasError: firstNameHasError,
    valueChangeHandler: firstNameChangeHandler,
    inputBlurHandler: firstNameBlurHandler,
    reset: firstNameResetHandler,
  } = UseInput((value) => value.trim() !== "");
  
  //------Using Input Hook for Last-Name
  const {
    value: enteredLastname,
    isValid: lastNameIsValid,
    hasError: lastNameHasError,
    valueChangeHandler: lastNameChangeHandler,
    inputBlurHandler: lastNameBlurHandler,
    reset: lastNameResetHandler,
  } = UseInput((value) => value.trim() !== "");
  //-------Using Input Hook for Email
  const {
    value: enteredEmail,
    isValid: emailisValid,
    hasError: emailHasError,
    valueChangeHandler: emailChangeHandler,
    inputBlurHandler: emailBlurHandler,
    reset: emailResetHandler,
  } = UseInput(isEmail);
  
  //setting form validation
  let formIsValid = false;
  if (firstNameIsValid && lastNameIsValid && emailisValid) {
    formIsValid = true;
  }
  //Handling Form submission
  const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(!formIsValid){
      return;
    }
    console.log("First-Name : ", enteredFirstName);
    console.log("Last-Name : ", enteredLastname);
    console.log("Email : ", enteredEmail);
    firstNameResetHandler();
    lastNameResetHandler();
    emailResetHandler();
  };
  console.log(firstNameHasError);
  // classes for first Name
  const firstNameInputClassess = firstNameHasError
  ? "form-control invalid"
  : "form-control";
  //classes for Last name
  const lastNameInputClassess = lastNameHasError
  ? "form-control invalid"
  : "form-control";
  //classes for Email
  const emailInputClasses = emailHasError
  ? "form-control invalid"
  : "form-control";
  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <div className="control-group">
        <div className={firstNameInputClassess}>
          <label htmlFor="name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" onChange={firstNameChangeHandler} onBlur={firstNameBlurHandler} value={enteredFirstName}
          />
          {firstNameHasError && (
            <p className="error-text">First Name must not be empty</p>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className={lastNameInputClassess}>
          <label htmlFor="lastname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="lastname" onChange={lastNameChangeHandler} onBlur={lastNameBlurHandler} value={enteredLastname}
          />
          {lastNameHasError && (
            <p className="error-text">Last name Must Not be empty</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={emailInputClasses}>
        <label htmlFor="name">E-Mail Address</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" onChange={emailChangeHandler}
        onBlur={emailBlurHandler} value={enteredEmail}/>
        {emailHasError&&(<p className="error-text">Please enter Email</p>)}
      </div>
      <div className="form-actions">
        <button disabled={!formIsValid}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default BasicForm;
```

Comment: where from the value comes inside UseInput hook?

Comment: Coming from Basicform